# Why is Java meta programmation support not better?

Tags: java, reflection, jpa, metaprogramming, jpa-2.0

I've always asked myself this question, particularly when i see how JPA 2.0 metamodel works...

For exemple in JPA 2.0 we can, with a processor, for an entity Entity, create a metamodel class Entity_

It's then possible in JPA 2.0 Criteria api to use this metamodel to have strongly typed criterias.

For exemple, you would write:

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(u.get(User_.username), username);
```

Instead of using the fieldname as string "username".

I just wonder why it's not handled natively in Java, without having to deal with a processor and a couple of extra metadata classes.

It's not just for JPA, it could leverage too the reflection api.

So are there reasons why we can't access the metadata directly in the java classes? 
Can someone provide a drawback of having such a feature?
I guess it may be a problem for encapsulation no?

---

For more infos about JPA2 metamodel:
http://www.inze.be/andries/2010/09/19/jpa2-metamodel-example/

Comment: Just one thing: can you mention a practical, real-world case for such a feature? I don't understand what you mean/want

Comment: The real-world usecase is obvious: be able to do what we do with JPA 2.0 criteria api with metamodels, but without having to deal with a processor that generates the metamodel classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 7 doesn't support methods or fields/properties as first class objects.  The reason these haven't been added is to keep the language simple.

However, it appears to me that Oracle has taken a different view (at least for methods) and you will be able to have method references in Java 8 and possibly one of the JSRs using field/property references will be accepted and merged into Java 8 or 9.

---

Some articles on how method handles are currently support. Java 8 will add syntactic sugar for this functionality.

http://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/method_handles_in_a_nutshell

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/DynTypeLang/

http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=191

Comment: thanks. And do you see any drawbacks of this approach for such things like encapsulation (i mean will we be able to get private method references for exemple)? Do you have a link with that information (JSR)?

Comment: I imagine the security model will be protected in the same manner as reflection does currently.